# Regex to replace all <br/> to <br> in PHP

Tags: php, html, string, replace

I would like to remove the slash in br

so attempt this code:

```
$data = str_replace('<br/>', 'br', $data);
```

the problem is , the slash is not removed, is it due to the html tag<> ? are there any workaround e.g. using regex for this case?

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: It works, Demo: https://eval.in/620744

Comment: Are you seeing `<br/>` in a browser, not in the source code? If so view the source it is probably `&lt;br/&gt;`.

Comment: You should perhaps use a regex indeed, which accounts for optional whitespace before the slash (which your question should mention, btw).

Comment: @AlokPatel Your replacement is different than the OPs, note the `<br>` vs `br`.

Comment: @chris85 Obviously it works with `br` when it works with `<br>` :)  https://eval.in/620745

Comment: @AlokPatel then why post the question? An `it works` should be a direct copy; the OP should post why the code doesn't work and what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to replace all possible `br` tag forms

```
$example = "<br /> <BR /> <br   /> <br/>";

echo preg_replace('#(<br */?>\s*)+#i', '<br />', $example);

// Output: <br> <br> <br> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace string should be `<br>`

```
$ php -r 'echo str_replace("<br/>", "<br>", "asdf<br/>asdf");'
asdf<br>asdf
```